# How to display a SVG in Visual Studio design?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, svg, visual-studio-2019

I have a SVG image and I want to display it in design. I use Visual Studio Community 2019. I tried to use `<asp:Image/>` control. With this control I can resize the SVG, but the image is not displayed. What should I do to display it in design?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Not displaying in which browsers? Some down level browsers need specific content types to display SVG.

Comment: In browser is displayed. But when I create an ASPX page in Visual Studio and i want to see the SVG image in design, it's now shown.

Answer (score 1):

It's not Visual Studio's native designer (i.e. doesn't appear in the designer tab), but I suspect either of these would give you the desired result..

1. VS extension "Markdown Editor"

   - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.MarkdownEditor
   - Be sure to right click file and use 'open with.. markdown editor'
   - Example..
     [image]
2. VS extension "SVG Viewer"

   - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.SvgViewer
   - Sets the default file handling automatically, but you can't zoom into the image wihtout zooming in the entire code editor window

Comment: The SVG Viewer extension works great.